# Kindle Fire playing embedded videos from .mobi file possible? and notes on other devices

Tags: html, html5-video, epub, kindle-fire

I'm working on an epub/mobi which has some embedded videos using the  , , and  tags. The  tags play on iPad iBook but not   and  plays in Kindle app (not sure about the other two tags. The videos play but not automatically on the Nook color (only plays some videos, has something to do with formatting of videos). But on the Kindle Fire the videos don't even render. Anyone have any how to get these to render on the Kindle Fire? and how to get them to autoplay on the Nook color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No at the moment it is not Possible.

Only Kindle for iPad/iPhone support audio/video

Kindle fire will not support mobi with enhancement.